# Custom view: nested linearlayout not showing up

Tags: android

I created a custom view. In it, theres a line, a textview, another line. beneath the bottom line, i wanted to put a new horizontally oriented linearlayout. when i run it, this nested linearlayout doesnt seem to show up at all. Instead, i can see the test button right underneath the bottom line. what am i doing wrong?

```
    public class MyView extends LinearLayout   {

        public MyView(Context context, Question question) {
            super(context);



    //      this.setLayoutParams(params);
            this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lineParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2);
            View topLine = new View(context);
            lineParams.setMargins(0, 15, 0, 0);
            topLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 159, 218));
            topLine.setLayoutParams(lineParams);

            this.addView(topLine);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            //Challenge Question
            TextView questionText = new TextView(context);
            questionText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            questionText.setTextSize(14);
            questionText.setLayoutParams(params);
            questionText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            questionText.setText(question.getQuestion());

            this.addView(questionText);

            View bottomLine = new View(context);
            bottomLine.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 159, 218));
            bottomLine.setLayoutParams(lineParams);


            this.addView(bottomLine);

            LinearLayout innerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams innerLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            innerLayout.setLayoutParams(innerLayoutParams);
            innerLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            innerLayout.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);


            //TableLayout for the multiple choices  
            TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context);
            LayoutParams tableLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //      tableLayoutParams.weight = .8f;
            tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tableLayoutParams);


            innerLayout.addView(tableLayout);
            this.addView(innerLayout);

            Button button = new Button(context);
            button.setLayoutParams(params);
            button.setText("testing 123");
            this.addView(button);
}
```

Note that I pasted the code without all the stuff that I added to the tablelayout. I probably should have pasted that too. But it didn't work when I did that either. but either way, if i set the nested linearlayout to 300 width and set a background color of red to it, i should at least see it, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what the height of the inner layout should be. Right now it is `wrap_content` and contains a `TableLayout` (with no rows) with its height also set to `wrap_content`. There doesn't seem to be anything in that inner layout giving it a height dimension, so that may be why it is not being displayed.

Trying the following will make your layout visible:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams innerLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
```

More usefully, you can try adding something with a real width/height to the `TableLayout`.

Also consider writing your layout in XML to [better separate your application logic and the presentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).

Comment: yea, as i said it didnt work when i added content to the tablelayout either, but yes im going to create the tablelayout in xml and add it to my custom view that way. its nice to have the flexibility of mixing and matching programmatic views with xml based views